# SCSS file import not found on Jekyll site hosted on Github pages

Tags: sass, jekyll, minima

I am getting this build error.

```
Your site is having problems building: Your SCSS file portfolio/assets/main.scss has an error on line 1: File to import not 
found or unreadable: minima. Load path:/hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.4/_sass.
```

I installed the Jekyll-Theme-Primer when I first started building this site and I didn't like it, so I removed it(or so I thought). Could someone help me locate the issue? I have already checked my config.yaml file, and Gem file. I've tried finding the Primer gem and I can't. Thank you for your time.

[Here is a link to the repo being built.](https://github.com/cheyenneprough/cheyenneprough.github.io)

Comment: Your *Gemfile.lock* does not represent what is in your *Gemfile*. Ideally your *Gemfile.lock* should be ignored in a *.gitignore*. Just try removing the file